# In tf.keras.layers.Embedding, why it is important to know the size of dictionary?

Tags: tensorflow, word-embedding

Same as the title, in tf.keras.layers.Embedding, why it is important to know the size of dictionary as input dimension?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In such setting, the dimensions/shapes of the tensors are the following:

- The input tensor has size `[batch_size, max_time_steps]` such that each element of that tensor can have a value in the range `0 to vocab_size-1`.
- Then, each of the values from the input tensor pass through an embedding layer, that has a shape `[vocab_size, embedding_size]`. The output of the embedding layer is of shape `[batch_size, max_time_steps, embedding_size]`.
- Then, in a typical seq2seq scenario, this `3D` tensor is the input of a recurrent neural network.
- ...

Here's how this is implemented in Tensorflow so you can get a better idea:

```
inputs = tf.placeholder(shape=(batch_size, max_time_steps), ...)
embeddings = tf.Variable(shape=(vocab_size, embedding_size], ...)
inputs_embedded = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embeddings, encoder_inputs)
```

Now, the output of the embedding lookup table has the `[batch_size, max_time_steps, embedding_size]` shape.

Comment: I thought the embedding layer is of size (batch, sequence, embedding_size)

Comment: Should be better now.

Comment: Ok then, so if we have input tensor of size [batch_size, max_time_steps] and embeding layer of size [vocab_size, embedding_size], how would the matrix multiplication work?

Comment: Because there is none, on top of the embedding layer there is a simple lookup table that just retrieves the correct embedding. I will post how is this implemented in Tensorflow to get the idea.

Comment: I think I understand now, I didn't think about the internal storage

Answer (score 7):

Because internally, the embedding layer is nothing but a matrix of size `vocab_size x embedding_size`. It is a simple lookup table: row `n` of that matrix stores the vector for word `n`.

So, if you have e.g. 1000 distinct words, your embedding layer needs to know this number in order to store 1000 vectors (as a matrix).

Don't confuse the internal storage of a layer with its input or output shape.
The input shape is `(batch_size, sequence_length)` where each entry is an integer in the range `[0, vocab_size[`. For each of these integers the layer will return the corresponding row (which is a vector of size `embedding_size`) of the internal matrix, so that the output shape becomes `(batch_size, sequence_length, embedding_size)`.

Comment: You say `Embedding()` layer is nothing more than a lookup table of embeddings, which makes sense to me. Outside of DL embeddings come from training `word2vec` or `Glove`. Where do embeddings come from for TF/Keras' `Embedding()` layer (which again you say is a lookup table)???

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov not sure if I fully understand your question. Embeddings can come from anywhere you want. As long as they are given as a matrix of the right shape, you can initialize the layer with it. And you also have the option of having them randomly initialized and trained during your training, just like any other layer.

Comment: You get it right, thanks!!! In the first case -- given as a matrix -- do I understand correctly embeddings are passed as `embeddings_initializer` param with shape equal to `[vocab_size x embedding_size]`? Should I also set them as "untrainable"? Can you update your answer with some code for both cases, or at least with some links elaborating on both cases (training embeddings I believe need at least some loss function).

Comment: This post https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/270546/how-does-keras-embedding-layer-work explains all the mechanics of `Embedding()` layer with some useful links.